# Looking for a link that checks if I have all the latest updates for my computer

Tags: windows-7, updates

I'm looking for a link that checks if I have all the latest updates for my computer. I know that it is on the Microsoft web site, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have Windows 7, it's built into the operating system. You can find it by typing "Windows Update" into the start menu's search bar, or by going to the control panel, under the "System and Security" section.

[image: Windows Update]

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you can't just use windows update?
Even on [Microsoft's website](http://www.update.microsoft.com), it tells you to do this.

Comment: I believe that is the exact website the poster was looking for; he just didn't know how to get there.